# Checking if a dynamic object that contain data from Invoking power shell script is null or > zero is not working on windows 2012 & IIS-8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC-5 web application, and i have a method which have a dynamic object that will be populated on run-time from invoking some power shell scripts. and i am checking if the dynamic object's child is null or its count `>` zero.

Now on our DEV machine (Windows Server 2008 R2 + IIS-7) the code worked well, while on the Live environments which is (Windows Server 2012 R2 + IIS-8) the code will fail to check if the dynamic object's child is null or its count =1. 
The associated method is as follow:-

```
    var shell = PowerShell.Create();
    string PsCmd = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core;$vCenterServer = '" 
+ vCenterName + "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword + "';" + System.Environment.NewLine;



    PsCmd = PsCmd + "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;



    PsCmd = PsCmd + "Get-VMHost " + System.Environment.NewLine;
    shell.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd);                                
    dynamic results = shell.Invoke(); // execute the first powercli script                            
    if (results != null && results.Count > 0 && results[0].BaseObject != null)
```

and here is a sample of the result on the Dev machine using visual studio, where the dynamic object `result` have a child named `result[0].BaseObject` :-

[image]

and on the live server , the same thing applies:-

[image]

now on the Dev machine the If statement (`if (results != null && results.Count > 0 && results[0].BaseObject != null)` ) will return true since the Result & its child `result[0].BaseObject` is not null. while on the Live server the IF statement condition `results[0].BaseObject != null` will return false although it exsits. so can anyone adivce what is causing this strange problem, i mean why on live server the IF statement return false for `results[0].BaseObject != null` while on Dev it will return true ?

Comment: Use a temporary variable to store the value of your condition expression. Watch *that* in your debugger.

Comment: @Amit ok  i will try now,, but what is causing this to not work correctly on live server ? i mean the result have a count =1 ..

Comment: I have no idea, but using a temporary variable might shed some light (and might not)

Comment: @Amit i edit my question where i added a temp variable which will have count=1 but the if statement will still fail...

Comment: `bool condition = results != null && results.Count > 0 && results[0].BaseObject != null;`. Observe that. If it's true and the `if` is skipped, call Microsoft. otherwise, start explaining why it's false.

Comment: now "bool condition = results != null && results.Count > 0 && results[0].BaseObject != null;" will be false ..

Comment: Exactly, and the problem is not with the if statement, it's with your condition, most probably `results[0].BaseObject != null` is false.

Comment: now i divided the check into three separate if statements and results[0].BaseObject != null will be false while the other IFs will be true,, although there is a record for result[0].BaseObject and again this code is working well on our dev machine .. so is there any work around to access the result[0].BaseObject ?

Comment: I have no idea what that object is, where it's coming from or what causes it to be null. Sorry, can't help without information.

Comment: i am running some powercli scripts to get info for the servers ,, and the result[0].BaseObject is the results obtained from Invoking some shell scripts ..

Comment: Sorry, no idea - but you should edit your question. There's so much going on there, and these big images... looks like most of it is completely irrelevant. Change your question, describe relevant information (what `result` is and so on), mention that `BaseObject` is only null on your server, and the world will (probably) help!

Comment: One difference i can think of is your dev machine (Server 2008 R2) has powershell 2.0 by default where as your live box is a Server 2012 R2 that has powershell 3.0 by default. Are you using same version of powershell and System.Management.Automation.dll in both boxes ?

Comment: but at the end the returned results as shown on VS are exactly the same ,, is this correct ?

Comment: @curiousgeek on Dev powershell version is 2 ,, while on live powershell version is 4 ,, but could this be causing the problem ? and how i can access the "results[0].BaseObject" on live server then ? while for the System.Management.Automation.dll  it should be the same since i have deployed the same web application .. is this correct ?

Comment: Yes it should be. May be you can try debugging on your dev box after installing powershell 4.0 and using that version to run your PS cmdlets, may be that might give some light into what's going on.

Comment: @curiousgeek i am debugging on live server i have installed VS also ..

Comment: @Amit not sure what is causing this . but i wrote the following results[0].Build and i was able to reference the Build ,,, so seems on windows server 2012 + IIS-8 there is no need to reference BasoObject as i used to do results[0].BaseObject.Build  ...

Comment: App Pool Pipeline.  I would look at what version of .NET was being used in each of the App Pools on the two machines for the site in question.

Comment: I do not know if PowerShell guarantees short circuit evaluation.  I would change the one line to about 5 if statements with extra null checks.

Comment: @SqlSurfer both have V4.0 for the application pool... and on windows 2012 i was able to reference the value without using BaseOject as follow:-  results[0].Build instead of  results[0].BaseObject.Build ... not sure why,, although on the Autos debugging the BaseObject is presented..